# jQuery Drag & Drop not setting background in IE - works on all other browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to set a background image to a DIV with jquery draggable and droppable. It works on all browsers but IE (at least IE 9 which I am testing on).

Could not find something wrong in the code, anyone has an idea why it does not work?

```
$(function() {
     $("#draggable1" ).draggable({helper:'clone'});
     $("#draggable2" ).draggable({helper:'clone'});
     $("#draggable3" ).draggable({helper:'clone'});
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $("#droppable").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(ui.draggable).attr("src") + ')');                    
            }
        });
 });
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/spairus/tXCjH/57/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesnt have by default console support which make script to stop, press F12 to open it or set  debugmode to false:

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tXCjH/69/)

```
var debugmode = false;
```

BTW, you could simplify your code to:

```
$("#draggable1,#draggable2,#draggable3" ).draggable({helper:'clone'});
```